# How to make HTML back button that scrolls to top?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to create a simple button link that sends users back one page in history but also to the top of that page instead of their previous position.

Ive been trying some html/javascrpit to achieve this but no avail. any suggestions?

```
<a href="#" onClick="history.go(-1);return true;window.scrollTo(0,0);"  class="btn home-button "> Back </a>
```

and/or

```
<a href="javascript:history.go(-1)" onclick="window.scrollTo(0,0);"  class="btn home-button "> Back </a>
```

The second piece of code does scroll to top but it happens before the page loads.

Comment: Can't control window in a different page from current page if it's not a single page app

Answer (score 0):

You can add this code in your first page or in js file:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function () {
  window.scrollTo(0, 0);
}
```

The other way is create a function to change the page.

```
function nextPage() {
   window.scrollTo(0, 0);
   document.location.href = "page2.html";
}
```

And finally your :

```
<a onclick="nextPage()" href="#"> Page 2 </a>
```

Comment: This caused every link on the site to scroll to top first and then load. But it is bringing me to top after the page loads too. Edit: I added it in the js file fyi

Comment: @Dunne08 I’ve update my answer, now u can added to specific link.